# jenkins Failed to parse POMs with variable

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a project with a single POM, in which I have some properties defined, like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
   
    <repository.release.id>release.repository.abc.com</repository.release.id>
    <repository.release.name>ABC Release Repository</repository.release.name>
    <repository.release.url>http://maven.abc.virtual/a/repository</repository.release.url>
    <repository.release.distribution.url>http://maven.abc.virtual/a/abc-internal-repo</repository.release.distribution.url>
   
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>${repository.release.id}</id>
        <name>${repository.release.name}</name>
        <url>${repository.release.url}</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<!-- other stuff ignored -->
```

**But Jenkins log goes**

```
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to transfer com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom:2.10.3 from ${repository.release.url} was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of ${repository.release.id} has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom:2.10.3 from/to ${repository.release.id} (${repository.release.url}): Cannot access ${repository.release.url} with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.2.RELEASE, /root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom, line 586, column 25

at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:364)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:361)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.readProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:331)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1328)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1125)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1074)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1057)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:986)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:691)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1816)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Apparently Jenkins fails to parse *${repository.release.id}* and *${repository.release.url}*, after I replace them with their real value, Jenkins succeeds the build.
So why Jenkins fails to parse them? which setting am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: In a CI environment like Jenkins you should never define repositories in your pom file. The correct location is the `settings.xml` file which can created by using config file provider plugin of jenkins including the credentials...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for you advice. I guess by putting repositories in pom file , we don't have to make sure the setting.xml has the repositories config in different deploy environment

Comment: Usually you don't put repositories in a pom file in general. You do that via `settings.xml` file and having a repository manager and making a repository based on deploy environment does not make sense from my point of view. The artifact is always the same so only the configuration is different which does not belong to the artifact...